# WMV type file not uploading on server by ajax

Tags: php, wordpress

After updating wordpress i can not able to upload wmv file on server via ajax submit other all type of media uploading but mwv file is not uploading even not display it’s temp path also.

Comment: Have you checked your servers error log? How big is the file and what is your max file upload size and post size in your configuration?

Comment: My file 25 mb and max file upload size is 250mb